# How can I have dynamic Email Config in cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp

I am trying to have a dynamic email config based on the user login. In config/mail.php I have tried like this.

config/mail.php

```
public $default= array(
    "host" => Configure::read("mail_host"),
    "port" => Configure::read("mail_port"),
    "username" => Configure::read("mail_username"),
    "password" => Configure::read("mail_password"),
    "transport" => Configure::read("mail_transport") 
);
```

But I am getting error

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

I have done like this, But as I am having lots of pages I have to do this for all the pages.

```
$Email = new CakeEmail("default");
$Email->config(array(
        'host' => Configure::read('mail_host'),
        'port' => Configure::read('mail_port'),
        'username' => Configure::read('mail_username'),
        'password' => Configure::read('mail_password'),
        'transport' => Configure::read('mail_transport')
    ));
```

So that I need to configure dynamically in mail.php. Is it possible please kindly give some solution.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: I am using CakePHP 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cake 2.0 uses `app/Config/email.php`
cf. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html
use the constructor to set the config dynamically:

```
class EmailConfig {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->default['host'] = Configure::read('mail_host');
        ...
    }
```